# What HTML/CSS markup paradigm do you believe is the best to use now?

Tags: html, css

I know there are various different ways to structure the markup for an HTML document styled with CSS.

The ones I know of are:

- Floating layouts
- Table-based layouts

I mostly use floating layouts with various different semantic containers (try to avoid div soup.)

However, I also know I don't know that much about the various different ways one can structure an HTML document and apply CSS rules.  I also have no idea which paradigm is best considering the emerging technologies of HTML5/CSS3 and the rendering engines on mobile/tablet devices.

Could someone with a lot more knowledge than me on the subject advise as to the best way to go currently?  Or the best book to purchase?

Comment: The best book is still the classic one. Check "CSS: The Missing Manual" By David Sawyer McFarland. I think it answers your question well.

Comment: I'm in the middle of Hardboiled Web Design and so far it's excellent. http://fivesimplesteps.com/books/hardboiled-web-design

Comment: @bertzzie thanks!  I'm guessing it doesn't cover the HTML5/CSS3/Mobile devices issue but it seems like it will give me a good foundation in "CSS/HTML The Right Way"

Comment: @Bryan Awesome Bryan, this looks like it hits the part of the question bertzzie didn't address :)

Comment: Bulletproof Web Design by Dan Cederholm is still relevant. It doesn't cover HTML5/CSS3, but does walk through a lot of solid approaches to HTML and CSS.

Comment: Good! Going to start HTML5 for Web Designers (Jeremy Keith) and CSS3 for Web Designers (Dan Cederholm) after Hardboiled. http://books.alistapart.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone with a lot more
>   knowledge than me on the subject
>   advise as to the best way to go
>   currently?

The best way to go is to learn about the technology. CSS layouts are beautifully explained in chapters 9 and 10 of the CSS 2.1 spec.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html

Take the time to read trough it. Once you've done that, you should have complete understanding of CSS lay-outing.